# How to prevent all tags from firing on certain pages?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I need to prevent *all* tags from firing on certain pages. I know it could be done by creating a Page View trigger firing on page URLs containing certain pattern and then using that trigger as an exception for all the tags. The problem is that I have hundreds of tags and this will require changing all of them and also all future tags must be created with this in mind. Is there a better way to set up something like this?

Comment: I found the easiest option is to write a short cli script that adds or removes triggers via the API. If thats something you would consider I try to bash up an example tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of solutions:

- Edit every single trigger manually. And yes it needs to be the trigger you can not create an exception trigger and add it to every tag.
- Export the json of you container and write a little script that edit every single trigger for you.

Going more in depth here is how to exclude a page from a trigger:

[image: exclude URL from trigger]

Here is how it looks like on the container JSON:

```
{
    "accountId": "",
    "containerId": "",
    "triggerId": "",
    "name": "DOM Ready",
    "type": "DOM_READY",
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "CONTAINS",
            "parameter": [
                {
                    "type": "TEMPLATE",
                    "key": "arg0",
                    "value": "{{Page URL}}"
                },
                {
                    "type": "TEMPLATE",
                    "key": "arg1",
                    "value": "example.com/path/to/exclude"
                },
                {
                    "type": "BOOLEAN",
                    "key": "negate",
                    "value": "true"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "fingerprint": "123456789"
}
```

Comment: Using export and import facilities looks like an acceptable solution for now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove GTM from these certain pages?

Comment: I should have been more clear, I'm looking for a solution that is manageable from the Tag Manager Admin itself after initial setup, i.e. adding a new page shouldn't require further code changes.